# Bootstrap 3 fluid layout with sidebar prevents vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a page with bootstrap 3 that has the main information on the left, and then a small side-bar on the right where additional links and graphs relating to the main info will go:
http://www.bootply.com/ZLB46jDSnU

Problem is if I use container-fluid for the main body (line 55), vertical scrolling is gone even though the sidebar needs it..If I change container-fluid to container, everything works nicely BUT the main body overlaps with my sidebar. Giving me the impression the fluid layout is what I want.

Does anybody know why this interferes with scrolling? Am I taking the wrong approach to have a sidebar divs independent the page content divs?

Comment: See this example of independent scrolling columns: http://bootply.com/5l9bZ7ZOt6

Comment: @Skelly thanks for the example! With some tweaking I've got this working perfectly. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with Skelly's help!

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
                        <div class="panel panel-default ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Shortcuts</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!--User details -->
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <li><a href="#/milestones">Milestones --»</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/appversions">Versions --»</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/reportcsv">CSV Report --»</a></li>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
                    <!--All apps -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="">
                        <!-- Default panel contents -->
                        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                            <b>Your Applications</b>
                         </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table-here></table-here>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```